# How to connect to kivy-remote-shell?

Tags: android, python, ssh, kivy

This seems to be a dumb question, but how do I ssh into the kivy-remote-shell?

I'm trying to use `buildozer` and seem to be able to get the application built and deployed with the command, `buildozer -v android debug deploy run`, which ends with the application being pushed, and displayed on my android phone, connected via USB.

However, when I try `ssh -p8000 admin@127.0.0.1` from a terminal on the ubuntu machine I pushed the app *from* I get `Connection Refused`.

It seems to me that there should be a process on the host (ubuntu) machine in order to proxy the connection, or maybe I just don't see how this works?

Am I missing something simple, or do I need to dig in a debug a bit more?

Answer (score 2):

When the app is running, the GUI will tell you what IP address and port to connect to.

Answer (score 1):

> 127.0.0.1

This indicates something has gone wrong - 127.0.0.1 is a standard loopback address that simply refers to localhost, i.e. it's trying to ssh into your current computer.

If this is the ip address suggested by kivy-remote-shell then there must be some other problem, though I don't know what - does it work on another device?

Comment: yes, this is the ip displayed.  Ok, I'm guessing that I should be able to see the android device listed under `ifconfig -a`, is that right?

Comment: `ifconfig -a` run where?

Comment: from ubuntu... I tried it today, by tethering my phone via usb the phone's interface shows up in `ifconfig -a` as `usb0`, but running kivy-remote-shell still shows the loopback... oh well.

Comment: No, ifconfig is irrelevant, it shows interfaces on the current machine. kivy-remote-shell is broadcasting on the phone's wifi connection (or should be). Is this turned on and otherwise working?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know you found the answer or not. But what i have understood is that you are trying to connect android device from Ubuntu. If I am right then (go on reading) you are following wrong steps.
**First** :- Your Ubuntu does not have ssh server by default so you get this error message.
**Second** :- You are using 127.0.0.1 address i.e your Ubuntu machine itself.

**Method to do this shall be**
Give your android machine a static address or if it gets dynamic its OK.
know the IP address of android and then from Ubuntu type`ssh -p8000 admin@IP_Of_andrid_device` and this should solve the issue.